# Prove $E(XY)=E(XE(Y|X))$

Tags: probability

Prove $E(XY)=E(XE(Y|X))$

Is this right?

$$
\begin{align}
E(XE(Y|X)) &= \sum_x x_iE(Y|X=x_i)*P(X=x_i)\tag1\\
 &=\sum_x\sum_y(x_iy_j*f_{y|x}(y_i|x_j)*f_x(x_i))\tag2\\
 &=\sum_x\sum_y(x_iy_j*f_{xy}(x_iy_i))\tag3\\
 &=E(XY)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Try to write down on each step where it follows exactly. Then it's easier to spot the mistakes and misunderstandings if they exists.

Comment: RHS of (1) is zero for any continuous random variable $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some already proven facts at your disposal it's a one line task:

$E(XE(Y|X)) = E(E(XY|X)) = E(XY)$.

Here the first equality is due to "putting back what is known" and the second by "law of iterated expectation".

Regarding your try to solve this by definition: You are mid way changing from discrete to continuous random variables (at least in a way), which are we dealing with? The idea behind it however seems correct to me.